# is there any max limit to deploy node project on HEROKU on free account?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, heroku-ci

Thanks for supporting!!!

I have some issues with my heroku account, I've created free account on heroku, and deploying my project after making changes,

previously it was working fine, till 18-19 no of deploy, now it is showing build error on heroku logs,

please suggest to me!

[image: e details]

Comment: can you show the actual errors?

Comment: sure, just wait

Comment: no worries! Let us know when you have more info.